# Got 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.'. MS Graph Api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an issue with the Microsoft Graph API.

1. I have registered a new app in the Azure portal
2. Added Application.ReadWrite.All and Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy application permissions
3. Click on the admin consent button

[empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dph52.png)

After that, I'm trying to get an access token by

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/12fb9222-8b6e-4006-a483-a87fa44621c3/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id=dc07d452-9ce1-4b0f-a1a6-4fb5b230a4bb
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type=client_credentials
client_secret={client_secret}
```

And I'm getting the token.
Token looks like that:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/12fb9222-8b6e-4006-a483-a87fa44621c3/",
  "iat": 1570007742,
  "nbf": 1570007742,
  "exp": 1570011642,
  "aio": "42VgYHi/n737QYBx8DrOTW5Ft0skAQ==",
  "app_displayname": "testapp",
  "appid": "dc07d452-9ce1-4b0f-a1a6-4fb5b230a4bb",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/12fb9222-8b6e-4006-a483-a87fa44621c3/",
  "oid": "24d9cd08-efaf-497b-b023-920cc208400a",
  "roles": [
    "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy",
    "Application.ReadWrite.All",
  ],
  "sub": "24d9cd08-efaf-497b-b023-920cc208400a",
  "tid": "12fb9222-8b6e-4006-a483-a87fa44621c3",
  "uti": "f38JDx5iw0Kkp16mnZIqAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1569224302
}
```

After that, I'm executing

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/bb4c22ea-632e-45d8-ad0f-2ba39cf399c1
```

And I'm getting app properties.

And finally I want to update my app properties and I'm trying execute

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/bb4c22ea-632e-45d8-ad0f-2ba39cf399c1
{
    "displayName": "displayName"
}
```

And I'm getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "1565bb72-8392-4ca7-bb20-02b40f5603bd",
      "date": "2019-10-02T09:23:57"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm confused. I have permissions for the API update application, but I got the error, please help.

Comment: Okay that's definitely weird. I can't spot any mistakes in your process, the token looks like it should work.

Comment: I just have created a new application with that token, but I'm still can't update the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug, I tried with client credentials and granted `Application.ReadWrite.All and Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` permissions. I encountered the same error as yours.

Then I tried with Delegated permission with a user login, it worked. You can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) or just call the api with [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

[image]

**Note:**

> APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change.
>   Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.